# A good way to store key to multiple values in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have a key value storage (dictionary) made up of:

```
key1 value1
key2 value1
key3 value3
key1 value4
key3 value4
and so on
```

I'd like to group these so the keys only appear once (sorting of keys is optional) and values:

```
key1 value1, value4
key2 value1
key3 value3, value4
```

The question: Is there a dedicated way to store the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to fix it. Used a key value storage (dictionary) where the keys are key1, key2, key3 and the values are a Set (or Array) of value1, value2, value3 etc.

Something along the line of:

```
keys do: [ :eachKey | (eachKey condition) ifTrue: [
    keyValueStorage at: eachKey ifAbsentPut: [ Set new. ]
    ( keyValueStorage at: eachKey ) add: value. ] ] .
```

Comment: You can also use `#groupedBy:`, e.g. `{ #key1 -> #value1. #key2 -> #value2. #key1 -> #value3. } groupedBy: #key`

Comment: also `at:ifAbsentPut:` normally takes a block as a second argument, so `[ Set new ]` ... so the Set is created only if needed

Comment: @Peter you need `(... groupedBy: #key) collect: [ :coll | coll collect: #value ]`, or you will end up with a dictionary where values are collections of associations

Comment: @Peter fixed, let that one slip.